# How to run functions in parallel using multiprocessing, while iterating over the functions arguments in python?

Tags: python, file, parallel-processing, directory, arguments

I have an arbitrary function, whose argument is a file, let's say `func(file(i))`. I have different directories, let's say `folder_id1, folder_id2, ..., folder_idn`. Inside each directory it has some number of `files(i)`, e.g. inside the folder_id2 there are the files `file(1), file(2), file(3)` - three files - each directory has a different number of files.

I want to run the function `func(file(i))` for each `file(i)` inside a specific folder in parallel using `multiprocessing`. So would be something like this:

```
def runInParallel(funcs):
  proc = []
  for func in funcs:
    p = Process(target=func)
    p.start()
    proc.append(p)
  for p in proc:
    p.join()


def foo(folder_id(i)):
    runInParallel(func(file(1)), func(file(2)), ..., func(file(n)))
```

However, I don't know how to set all the functions `func(file(i))` at the same time as argument of the function `runInParallel()`. An option would be to iterate over the files `file(n)` inside the folder `folder_id(i)`, but then it wouldn't run in parallel.

Any idea? `Locals()`?

Thanks

Edit:

```
def interface(id, number):
    directory_name = f"{str(id)}_site_{str(number)}"


    relative_path = os.getcwd()

    file_path = os.path.join(relative_path, "output")
    output_directory = os.path.join(file_path, directory_name)
    os.chdir(output_directory)
    df = np.load('Principal.npy')
    print(df.shape)

    model_directory = os.path.join(relative_path, "modelos", directory_name)
    paths = [os.path.join(model_directory, filename) for filename in os.listdir(model_directory)]
    file_path = [path for path in paths if os.path.isfile(path)]


    f.runInparallel(paths, tms.desagregadorLSTM(, df=df))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go is to obtained the full paths of all the files present in in the given `folder_id(i)`. Then you can pass this `file_paths` and `func` to the `runInParallel` which then applies the `func` to each of the file parallely. . 
You also have to modify the `func` function so that it can take `file_path` as argument.
Here is the code which facilitates this task,

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

def runInParallel(file_paths, func):
    proc = []
    for path in file_paths:
        p = Process(target=func, args=(path,))
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)

    for p in proc:
        p.join()


def foo(folder_id):
    paths = [os.path.join(folder_id, filename) for filename in os.listdir(folder_id)]
    file_paths = [path for path in paths if os.path.isfile(path)]

    runInParallel(file_paths, func)
```

OR, Instead of using `Process` you can use `multiprocessing.Pool` to facilitate this task,

```
def runInParallel(file_paths, func):
    with Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(func, file_paths)
```

---

UPDATE (As per your comments):

if `modelo` is file object, update your `desagregadorLSTM` method as,

```
def desagregadorLSTM(path, df, medicoes=96): 
    with open(path, "r") as modelo:
        model = load_model(modelo) 
        model.summary() 
        df = df 
        X, y = f.separar_interface(df, n_steps=40)
        X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 2, 20, X.shape[2]) 
        y = y.reshape(y.shape[0], 40, 1) 
        test_predictions = model.predict(X).flatten() 
        y = y.flatten()
```

The call,

```
runInParallel(file_paths, tms.desagregadorLSTM)
```

Alo update,

```
p = Process(target=func, args=(path, df), kwargs={"medicoes": 96 })
```

Comment: My function `foo()` has a parameter which is the file. it is like foo(modelo=file, df=df). The second parameter I set it before, but it still is asking for the first parameter. `TypeError: desagregadorLSTM() missing 1 required positional argument: 'modelo'`

Comment: `def desagregadorLSTM(modelo, df, medicoes=96):
    model = load_model(modelo)
    model.summary()
    df = df
    X, y = f.separar_interface(df, n_steps=40)
    X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 2, 20, X.shape[2])
    y = y.reshape(y.shape[0], 40, 1)
    test_predictions = model.predict(X).flatten()
    y = y.flatten()`

Comment: And how exactly are you calling this function?

Comment: I get this message back: `NameError: name 'df' is not defined`